# How to differ between Windows Mobile 6.5.3 and previous versions during runtime?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, winapi, compact-framework

Is there an established or unofficial way of finding out if my application is running on a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 device or if it's a previous version? Managed or native doesn't matter and I don't mind interop-ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I want some reputation ;)

Here is the information I found on the web:
[How to detect Windows Mobile 6.1 (Detecting AKUs)](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/337)
[List of AKUs on channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/mobiledeveloper/listofakus/)
[Windows CE / Windows Mobile Versions](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/wce/versions.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Use [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)

That gets the CE version number, which would have to be translated to OS Version number with a lookup table. The best I can find at the moment is [here](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/wce/versions.htm), but its not yet up to date with the newest versions.

Comment: @PaulG: Thanks, but that just gives me *{Microsoft Windows CE 5.2.23090}*. To map that to WM 6.5.3 I would have to know between what max and min build number in the OSVersion that the WM 6.5.3 are valid.

Comment: Yep, I'm just looking for that info, but struggling to be honest!

Comment: Is this the missing piece of info? http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/wce/versions.htm.
This should also be useful: http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/mobiledeveloper/listofakus/

Comment: @Shaihi: Great info. Write an answer if you want some rep. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Shaihi. I had already added the link to that table, but it is unfortunately missing the required info.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/501/Default.aspx) can help:

Comment: In general, the info is fine, but some of it don't apply to .Net CF.