# CF - TreeView look on 6.0 and 6.5 device

Tags: compact-framework, treeview

I have a treeView with checkboxes and with image list.

Im trying to fix its look on both devices 6.0 and 6.5 but i cant get it to work. Either its ok on one device and looks crappy on the other.

The checkboxes are so small on 6.5 that i cant even tap them. If i change the font i get huge checkboxes and text on 6.0 device. Also i dont know how to set the image size so it would look good on both devices.

Can i get any tip how to handle this the proper way?

thanx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate resources that you set at runtime [based on the platform on which you're running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904104/how-to-differ-between-windows-mobile-6-5-3-and-previous-versions-during-runtime/2905078#2905078).

Comment: Hmmm ... the problem are pictures in imageList. I think that making a factory class and checking registry for device os version or screen resolution is not the proper way. Is there some DPI option that would resize the image properly by itself?

Comment: Not that works well or that generates images that don't look terrible, no.

Comment: actualy the correct way is to figure out the DPI of the device. Divide that by 96 and you get 1pixed equivalent to all devices. All values (width, height) have to be multiplied with that result...